# remove every instance of new line between two patterns

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with multiple instances of strings like this:

```
Query= XYZL01000001.1_wekjasdlpoa_strain_NLLLRL_WC-
3ssss66_P2sss0contig1.1__whole_genome_shotgun_sequence

Length=239131
```

which I need to format like this:

```
Query= ABC000001.1_wekjasdlpoa_strain_NLLLRL_WC-3ssss66_P2sss0contig1.1__whole_genome_shotgun_sequence

Length=239131
```

Basically, I need to delete the new line after the "Query= " pattern and before the "Length=" pattern, preserving the new line between those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via `sed`, with the `N` command:

```
sed '/^Query= / {N ; s/\n//g}' file
```